# Create view in MVC causes an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a student class like this :

```
namespace DomainClasses
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            this.Scores = new HashSet<Score>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string IntNo { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string BirthLocation { get; set; }
        public string Birthday { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Major { get; set; }
        public string Degree { get; set; }
        public string IdentNo { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Score> Scores { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This class has a repository class to handle requests :

```
public  class StudentRepository
{
        readonly EducationDBEntities _dbcontext = new EducationDBEntities();

        public void AddNewStudent(Student student)
        {
            _dbcontext.Students.Add(student);
        }

        public void RemoveStudent(Student student)
        {
            _dbcontext.Students.Remove(student);
        }

        public List<Student> GetStudentlist()
        {
            return _dbcontext.Students.ToList();
        }

        public Student FindStudentById(int id)
        {
            return _dbcontext.Students.Find(id);
        }

        public void Update(Student student)
        {
            _dbcontext.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

When I try to create a student model using create view in MVC I got this error :

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

So this exception comes from the `Save` method of the repository class. I mean when I want to save the context I got this error.

My student controller to create the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Student student)
{
     obj.AddNewStudent(student);
     obj.Save();
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
}
```

I create this model using EF6,

Comment: So what does 'EntityValidationErrors' say?

Comment: Did you see the EntityValidationErrors for more details?

Comment: how does your DB Scheme for student looks like?

Comment: @Szymon:how can i do that ?No

Comment: I can't find EntityValidationErrors :((

Comment: @knightsb:you mean my DB structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Try seeing the [`EntityValidationErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.validation.dbentityvalidationexception.entityvalidationerrors%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) property for more details. Replace `_dbcontext.SaveChanges();` with

```
try
{
    _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException validationException)
{
     // Just use the debugger to inspect validationException
     // here, or output EntityValidationErrors in some way.
}    // <== You can set a breakpoint here.
```

Comment: It says .the student id field is required ?why ?

Comment: *It's auto increament* makes me think you're using MySQL and not MSSQL. It shouldn't be necessary but you might try annotating `Id` with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]`

Comment: As you can see in my student class i have this field.but the mvc doesn't include it in create view ?

Comment: I was wrong sorry .it isn't auto increament ,the mvc doesn't include it in view

Comment: Well it doesn't have an ID until after it's created.

Comment: Seems like your database table is not consistent with your data model. Change the Id field in the database to auto-increment.